# Can we use Firebase with Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: firebase, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I was wondering if it was possible and also, if someone can give his testimony of using both. Actually, for me, the real time thing is not that important, I care more about the NoSQL Database. I really care about pricing and I can see that Firebase prices are okay for almost everything (authentication is even free),  but database is very expensive in my opinion (5$/giga stored and 1$/Giga downloaded ...). That's why I want to use DynamoDB for the database because it's way cheaper.

What do you think?

Comment: It's not actually clear whether you thoroughly understand the pricing model for either product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, Firebase just released a new NoSQL service that is somehow similar to DynamoDB. No need to connect to DynamoDB anymore!